# Can't reach an specific element by jquery: Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is my first question here. So be fair, please. :)

I don't get it.. I think my syntax isn't wrong but I only get an undefined object back from jquery. I try to pick an specific a tag element with the attribute-selector from jquery and after that I go down in the DOM till the last div before my img. At last I picked the img with the .find method.

Here is my code:

```
var cURL = $(this).find("img").attr("name");        
console.log($("a[href=cURL] > div.image-box > div.image-content").find("img").attr("src"));
```

The var `cURL` contains the right parameter as a string.

And the HTML/DOM:

```
<div class="product-wrapper...">
  <div class="product-cell...">
   <a class="image-wrapper" href="myArticle50">
     <div class="image-box..">
       <div class="image-content">
         <img alt="..." src="media/testArticle/.../myArticle50.jpg">
       </div>
     </div>
   </a>
   ....
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case my var cURL would contain 'myArticle50' and I need the src from the img -> 'media/testArticle/.../myArticle50.jpg'. But I only get an undefined back.

May you see my failure in the code.. :/

Kind Regards.

Comment: `$("a[href=" + cURL + "]...` `cURL` is a variable, but you've used it as the literal "cURL" in the selector.

Comment: `console.log($("a[href="+cURL+"] > div.image-box > div.image-content").find("img").attr("src"));`try this

Comment: Thank you all :) Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes, first:

This

```
console.log($("a[href=cURL] > div.image-box > div.image-content").find("img").attr("src"));
```

Should look like this

```
console.log($("a[href=" + cURL + "] > div.image-box > div.image-content").find("img").attr("src"));
```

and your class

```
<div class="image-box..">
```

Shouldn't have dots.

```
<div class="image-box">
```

Fix these, and your code should work fine and dandy.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. The dots are only to show that there are more classes. The original code haven't dots in it.